# Define the relation `subsum(Set,Sum,Subset)`

Tags: prolog

I have a problem.

> Define the relation `subsum(Set,Sum,Subset)` such that Set is a multiset of numbers expressed using lists, Subset is a subset of Set, and Sum is the union of the elements of Subset. The following results are obtained.
>
> ```
> ?- subsum([1,2,5,3,2],5,Sub).
> Sub = [1, 2, 2] ;
> Sub = [2, 3] ;
> Sub = [5] ;
> Sub = [3, 2] ;
> false.
> ?-
> ```
>
> The answers must not use any relationship other than the answer.

My answer is:

```
subsum([], 0 ,[]).
subsum([_ | Xs], Sum, Ys) :- subsum(Xs, Sum, Ys).
subsum([X | Xs], Sum, [X | Ys]) :- subsum(Xs, Sum - X, Ys).
```

But this code does not work as I expected.
Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you give me some hints?

Trace the code; e.g. from SWISH:

[image: Example trace from SWISH]

Your first line is `subsum([], 0 ,[]).` which can only match if the desired sum is `0` but if there are no elements which sum to the target, there won't be a `0` in the middle when it's called.

---

`subsum(Xs, Sum - X, Ys)` run this:

```
Sum = 5,
Y = 2,
writeln(Sum - Y)
```

What do you expect it to write? What does it actually write?